# Datanode having trouble with JVM pausing

Tags: java, hadoop, garbage-collection, jvm, cloudera-cdh

I am on CDH 5.1.2, I am seeing this error with one of the datanode pausing often. i see this from logs.

```
 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.JvmPauseMonitor: Detected pause in JVM or host machine (eg GC): pause of approximately 12428ms
GC pool 'ConcurrentMarkSweep' had collection(s): count=1 time=12707ms
```

Any Idea why i am seeing this? once a while hdfs capacity is dropping by one node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> GC pool 'ConcurrentMarkSweep' had collection(s): count=1 time=12707ms

You're experiencing a long GC pause with the CMS collector.

To investigate further you should turn on GC logging via `-Xloggc:<path to gc log file> -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails` and in case you're on java 7 also add `-XX:+PrintGCCause`.

[GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) can help visualizing the logs.

Once you've found the cause you can try adjust CMS to avoid those pauses. For starters, there is the [official CMS tuning guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html).

Answer (score 3):

We just encountered a very similar issue running CDH 5.3.2 where we were unable to successfully start the HDFS NameNode Service on our Hadoop Cluster.

At the time it was very puzzling as we weren't observing any apparent ERRORs in the /var/log/messages and /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/NAMENODE.log.out other than ***WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.JvmPauseMonitor: Detected pause in JVM or host machine (eg GC)***

After working with Cloudera Support we were able to determine that we were running into an OOM Exception that wasn't being logged... as a general rule of thumb take a look at the configuration of your Heap Sizes... for every 1 Million Blocks you should have at least 1GB of Heap Size.

In our case, the resolution was as simple as increasing the Java Heap Size for the NameNode and Secondary NameNode Services and Restarting... as we had 1.5 Million Block but were only using the default 1GB setting for heap size.  After increasing the Java Heap Size and restarting the HDFS Services we were green across the board.

Cheers!